# How to fix random invalid syntax

Tags: python, pygame

Invalid syntax is popping up for no reason and I am not sure what to do next. The code that is causing the issue is very important and I don't want to mess it up.

I tried deleting that line, running the module, then I tried writing the line back, the same error pops up.

Code related to issue at the top:

```
pygame.init()
game_width = 1000
game_height = 650
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((game_width, game_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
```

Code related to issue at the bottom:

```
pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(50)
pygame.display.set_caption("MY GAME fps: " + str(clock.get_fps()))
```

Code above first pygame:

```
import pygame

# Set up the Enemy's brain
class Enemy():
#Enemy constructor function
def __init__(self):
    # Make the Enemy's varaible
    self.x = 30
    self.y = 30
    self.pic = pygame.image.load("../assets/Fish04_A.png")

    # Enemy update function (stuff to happen over and over again)
    def update(self, screen):
    screen.blit(self.pic, (self.x, self.y)()
```

I expected the game to run with no errors, but this error popped up for the first time. The error says "Invalid Syntax and highlights the "p" in the first pygame. I am using Python IDLE version 3.8

Comment: What error? Please show us the error message. By the way, errors never occur "for no reason", however confused we may be about why they occur, you can always assume there is a reason.

Comment: Your code seems to be running OK. Is the line `code related to issue at bottom:` and `Code related to issue at top:` part of the code? If that was the case then you should comment it out or remove it because that is just an instruction for the reader.

Comment: Did you add the line `import pygame` at the beginning of your file?

Comment: Yes I did add import pygame at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Is there any code above the first pygame?

Comment: The error is often above the marked place.

Comment: there is a comment above and then some code

Comment: but the code that is causing the issue is the code to start the game and the code above is stuff inside the game that was added after, code was working fine when first started up the game

Comment: Could you post your entire script? It might be easier to debug that way. If it is too large than 5-10 lines above the first pygame should be sufficient

Comment: import pygame

# Set up the Enemy's brain
class Enemy():
    #Enemy constructor function
    def __init__(self):
        # Make the Enemy's varaible
        self.x = 30
        self.y = 30
        self.pic = pygame.image.load("../assets/Fish04_A.png")
        
    # Enemy update function (stuff to happen over and over again)
    def update(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.pic, (self.x, self.y)()

Comment: Indentation for `def update:` is wrong.

Comment: There's paranthesis missing here: `screen.blit(self.pic, (self.x, self.y)()` or one extra.

Answer (score 1):

As @hpaulj and @Austin mentioned, you forgot to add indentation for function `__init__` and `update` and the `screen.blit(self.pic, (self.x, self.y)()` line should be changed to `screen.blit(self.pic, (self.x, self.y))`

```
import pygame

# Set up the Enemy's brain
class Enemy():
    #Enemy constructor function
    def __init__(self):
        # Make the Enemy's varaible
        self.x = 30
        self.y = 30
        self.pic = pygame.image.load("../assets/Fish04_A.png")

        # Enemy update function (stuff to happen over and over again)
    def update(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.pic, (self.x, self.y))

pygame.init()
game_width = 1000
game_height = 650
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((game_width, game_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
```

Comment: It worked thanks for helping me, was dealing with a problem for about a day and then finally fixed it today.